# SQLite using local db in project folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm just starting out with SQLite and Visual basic.

the SQLconnection's data source is hardcoded as you can see:

```
Dim sqlconn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\User\Justin\Documents\project1\Members.db")
```

I know this would cause problems when wanting to run the program on another machine.
how would I go about in having the data source always point to the db in the project folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following steps to access the db file in the project folder.

First, please copy your db file to your project\bin\debug\ folder, like the following:

```
\TestConsole\bin\Debug\MyDatabase.sqlite
```

Second, please configure your connectionstring in your app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="SQLiteDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Finally, you can use the following code to access the db file directly.

```
Dim m_dbConnection As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite")
m_dbConnection.Open()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it with SQLite but I assume that it would work the same way as for SQL Server Express and Access data files:

```vb
Dim sqlconn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Members.db")
```

That place-holder will resolve to a dedicated folder for ClickOnce apps, the App_Data folder for Web Forms apps (maybe all ASP.NET apps; not sure) and the program startup folder otherwise.